# Apple Numbers SUMIF with multiple conditions

Tags: numbers

I recently switched to Numbers from Mac Excel and a formula is not working. I am taking the sum of a range of cells where a SUMIF condition is met. The formula worked in Mac Excel but Apple Numbers returns an error "The formula contains a number outside the valid range." It's obvious that SUMIF condition syntax is not valid in Numbers, but I cannot find any documentation or example to correctly format it. I have looked at SUMIFS with the same result.

For example, this works in Numbers

```
SUM(SUMIF(A2:A114,{"Blue"},F2:F114))
```

but this does not

```
SUM(SUMIF(A2:A114,{"Blue","Green","Black"},F2:F114))
```

Please use a working formula example in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [REGEX](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/ffac65c37db4/web):

```
SUMIF(A2:A114,REGEX("Blue|Green|Black"),F2:F114)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
SUM(SUMIF(A2:A114,"Blue",F2:F114),SUMIF(A2:A114,"Green",F2:F114),SUMIF(A2:A114,"Black",F2:F114))
```

Comment: Thx for posting your solution. I don't think Apple claims Numbers can fully replace Excel in functionality. However, Numbers can still do a lot of things and it also has some nice features that Excel does not have plus it comes free with any Apple device running iOS / iPadOS / macOS!

Comment: Excellent points. Can't beat free over another hundred-plus bucks to upgrade Mac:Excel.